# Command line ImageMagick gutter and crop-marks

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

For almost 4 days I searched for a command how I could add a crop-mark to my image.

I have installed ImageMagick software as well. I tried so many commands but am not able to crop with adding proper gutter and a crop mark.

> My image should look like this after the conversion:
>   https://alphagraphicslisle.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/gutter-2.png?w=540

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you would know the dimensions of the crop area, you would use [ImageMagick's Draw commands](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/) to add trim/crop lines.

If your source image does not have a bleed region, you can generate one with an Edge virtual pixel.

```
convert rose: -set option:distort:viewport 90x66-10-10 \
        -virtual-pixel Edge -filter point -distort SRT 0 \
        +repage rose_with_bleed.png
```

<sub>(***Note:*** The `rose:` input image is a special name, using a **built-in** demo image that's present in every ImageMagick installation.)</sub>

Simplest/fastest way I can think of a solution would be to..

- Draw trim-lead lines first
- Composite image over lead
- Draw crop rectangle over image

**Example:**

```
convert -size 110x86 xc:white \
        -strokewidth 1 -stroke gray \
        -draw 'line 20  0  20 86 line  90  0  90  86' \
        -draw 'line  0 20 110 20 line   0 66 110  66' \
        rose_with_bleed.png \
        -geometry 90x66+10+10 -composite \
        -stroke red -fill transparent \
        -draw 'rectangle 20 20 90 66' \
        out.png
```

[image: ImageMagick gutter and crop-marks]

Comment: Hi sir, I have tried executing above command but its not working giving me so many errors.http://pastebin.com/DqUexTRF

Comment: C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures>convert -size 110X86 xc:white \ -strokewidth 1 -stroke gray -draw 'line 20  0  20 86 \ -draw line  90  0  90  86' \ -draw 'line  0 20 110 20 \-draw line
 0 66 110  66' \ Chrysanthemum.jpg \ -geometry 90x66+10+10 -composite \ -stroke red -fill transparent \ -draw 'rectangle 20 20 90 66' out.jpeg

Comment: @ProfessionRakesh, the errors you posted are related to escape characters. Replace Unix escape symbol (\\) with Windows (^). Also quotes are missing, or unbalanced, around the `-draw` operations. If you haven't already, please take the time to read the [Usage under Windows](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/windows/).

Comment: Sir, What will be correct command any idea i have given double quotes near draw command instead of single quote.i am working on windows 7 command prompt help is needed?

Comment: Sir Thanks a lot finally its working but only small issue is gutter green dotted line is not showing